# «В чём стоит вопрос» или «О чём стоит вопрос»?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно сказать: "в чем стоит вопрос?" или "о чем стоит вопрос?"

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

Обе фразы нелитературны. Правильно:

- В чём состоит вопрос?
- Чего *(кого)* касается вопрос?
- О чём *(о ком)* вопрос?
- В чём суть вопроса?

Использованы материалы «Большого универсального словаря русского языка» под ред. В. В. Морковкина.

Answer (score 0):

> В чём **со**стоит вопрос?
>
> О чём *ставится* вопрос?

(требуется конкретизировать, что из многословно сказанного является вопросом)

> *Как* стоит вопрос?

(требуется пояснить, что нужно сделать, каковы последствия решения или нерешения вопроса)